# Regex matching a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to extract only the sign and numbers from the data

Input: `<70 (aze) , <0,03 (+) , >0.03 (+)`
Output: `<70 , <0,03 , >0.03`

Trying with `re.sub` but I can't pick the sign

```py
re.sub("\D", "", text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
" , ".join(re.findall(r'[<>]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?', text))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF1G5y/1). *Details*:

- `[<>]?` - an optional `<` or `>`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of `.` or `,` and then one or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/omgjgv):

```py
import re
text = '<70 (aze) , <0,03 (+) , >0.03 (+)'
print( " , ".join(re.findall(r'[<>]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?', text)) )
# => <70 , <0,03 , >0.03
```

In Pandas:

```py
df['text'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'[<>]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?').str.join(' , ')
```

Comment: my data is a dataframe, and I have also clean values like normal numbers; any idea how i can apply that

Comment: the data is vertical, i wrote the "," to separate examples, each cell contains one value. So far applying the findall with the regex you gave gives null everywhere

Comment: @ombk Please share a reproducible example, a sample df at least. `df['text'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'([<>]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)', expand=False)` should work on string data.